# Fix dependency issues with Create-React-App

Tags: reactjs, node.js, dependencies, babeljs, create-react-app

I want to create a react-app but i am getting some bunch of error messages about my dependencies.

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple minutes.    
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead. 
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.   
npm WARN deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
npm WARN deprecated abab@2.0.6: Use your platform's native atob() and btoa() methods instead
npm WARN deprecated domexception@2.0.1: Use your platform's native DOMException instead
npm WARN deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm WARN deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.     
npm WARN deprecated workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0: workbox-background-sync@6.6.0
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

added 1462 packages, and audited 1463 packages in 3m      

242 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app.
Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.
You can fix this by running npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app before using create-react-app again.
```

I have tried fixing it by running

> npm uninstall -g create-react-app

My folder structure only has my node_modules, package.json and package.lock.json. There is no src and public folder.

Answer (score 0):

create-react-app is deprecated, use something like [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project) instead.

[Goodbye create-react-app](https://dev.to/ag2byte/create-react-app-is-officially-dead-h7o)

Answer (score 0):

run npm or yarn command on your terminal.

## npm 7+, extra double-dash is needed:

```
npm create vite@latest my-react-app -- --template react
```

## yarn

```
yarn create vite my-react-app --template react
```

docs: https://vitejs.dev/guide/

Answer (score 0):

use
**npm create vite@latest my-react-app -- --template react**

**create-react-app** is no longer supported but it should work but not recommended